# Undefined symbol "_ThreadRuneLocale"

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, freebsd

Recently I have compiled my application (`so` library) on my FreeBSD 9.2 using gcc49. When I am trying to run it on my dedicated server (FreeBSD 9.0)

I am getting this error message:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: Undefined symbol "_ThreadRuneLocale"
```

I've been trying to copy the `libstdc++.so.6` from `/usr/local/lib/gcc49/` from the machine the library was compiled on to the dedicated server machine but it did not helped.

Are there any other solutions for this problems?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update to FreeBSD-9.1 at least.

Comment: I spend about 5 hours to solve this problem. I have even updated to the FreeBSD 9.1 - nothing helped. Interesting fact is that, when I was compiling my `so` on my old machine (FreeBSD 9.1) I could run the  library without any problems on the FreeBSD 9.0.